# Is arbitrary union of positive sets a positive set?

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

Let $\nu$ be a signed measure on $(X,\mathcal{M})$. We call the set $E$ positive if $\nu(F)\geq 0$ for any $F\subseteq E$. For a sequence $\{E_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ of positive sets, it's easy to check that $\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_j$ is also a positive set. Intuitively, the sum of positive measure is still positive. However, given a sequence $\{G_i\}_{i\in I}$ of positive sets for uncountable index set $I$, do we have $\bigcup_{i\in I}G_i$ being a positive set?

Technically, I think it's not a positive set since the uncountable union of measurable set might not be in $\mathcal{M}$ anymore. Is my reasoning correct? However, I feel that the intuition "sum of positive measures should be positive" still holds here.

Comment: You don't even need to go to non-measurable sets to get a counterexample. Note that $X=\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$. Now can you find an example of a signed measure space where all singletons get nonnegative measure but where there is a set with negative measure?

Comment: This reminds me of a problem I answered as an undergraduate. The professor didn’t know the answer off the top of his head for the original student’s question, so I gave an answer very comparable to Noah Schweber’s hint, asking if it was the right idea. :)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for your hint! Does the following work? Let $\nu(E)=\int_{E}fd\mu$ where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure and $f=1$. Then for any $x_0\in [0,1]$, $\nu(\{x_0\})=0$ which is non-negative. However, $\nu([0,1])=-1$ which is negative. If this is a correct example, what would be the underlying intuition? Is that we are adding too many sets s.t. the "negative" are able to appear.

Comment: Sorry, I mean by $f=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint by Noah Schweber, consider the signed measure $\nu(E)=\int_{E}fd\mu$ where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure. Note that $E$ is a positive set if $f\geq 0$ almost everywhere. However, the uncountable union accumulates null sets into a set with a non-zero measure. That is, let $f=-1$ and $E=(0,1]$. Let $\{x_i\}_{x_i\in E}$ be a sequence of positive sets. However, $\nu(\bigcup_{i} {x_i})=\nu(E)=-1$ which is not a positive set.